# Display notice at Woocommerce Checkout if weight greater than or equal to 224kg

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, checkout

I've seen a couple of similar answers, but not quite what I need. Basically I just want to display a notice to show at checkout when the total order weight is 225kg or over.

Based on [Display weight and the remaining weight message on woocommerce cart and checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721484/display-weight-and-the-remaining-weight-message-on-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout) answer code, here is my adapted code:

```
    // Display a custom shipping message when cart weight exeeds a limit
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'display_total_weight_notice' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'display_total_weight_notice' );
function display_total_weight_notice( $message ) {
    // DEFINE the allowed weight limit
    $cart_total_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

    if( cart_total_weight >= 225 ) :

    wc_print_notice( sprintf(
        __( 'Your order has a total weight of %s. This will be shipped via Pallet Delivery, by continuing you agree to the following:<br><br> 
        > Ground/Road around the property will be flat, level and solid. <br> 
        > Standard Delivery will take place between 9am-5pm and will require a signature. You can advise a safe place to leave your order, however this is at the driver’s discretion to do so, we hold no responsibility if left. <br> 
        > Where a delivery cannot be made due to access, a re-delivery can be made at your request for a charge of £45.00 per pallet on the following day or when arranged. <br> 
        > In any cases of Damages/Shortages you will note this on the delivery note when you Sign for it, and then contact us right away. No refunds/replacements will be given if damages are not noted at delivery. <br> 
        > Pallet Orders cancelled en route, or returned due to ground Conditions/Access Restrictions will incur a return fee of £45 per pallet (subject to location), deducted from any refunds given. <br> 
       >  Orders over 1000kg will require your own forklift. 

' ),
        '<strong>' . wc_format_weight($cart_total_weight) . '</strong>',
    ),'notice' );

    endif;
}
```

But it's not working for me.

Comment: What's the issue with your code? Nothing is displayed? Is it executed at least on checkout or cart page?

Comment: No notice is showing up on the cart page, even when adding items totalling over 225kg

Comment: I adapted from here if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721484/display-weight-and-the-remaining-weight-message-on-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout

Comment: The code works if you add the missing `$` on the variable `$cart_total_weight` in your if statement...

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code, and it correctly displays a message on cart page.

There's just a typo in your code, your missing the `$` before your variable:

```
if( $cart_total_weight >= 225 ) :
```

When setting at least one product with a weight, I get the correct total weight from     `$cart_total_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();`. If no product in cart as a weight defined, it correctly returns 0.

If you haven't edited the cart template, it should work. If you edited it, check that the `do_action()` is still here.

[image]

Here I edited the limit to 20kg to display the message, with a product of 25Kg to match the criterias.

Answer (score -1):

Managed it with

```
// Display a custom shipping message when cart weight exeeds a limit
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'checkout_required_min_weight_mood' );
function checkout_required_min_weight_mood () {
    
    // only on the cart and check out pages
    if( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) return;

    // Get the Cart's content total weight
    $total_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

    // here the minimum weight
    $minimum_weight = 225; // 225 kg

    // If the total weight is less than the minimum, we avoid payment and display an error notice
    if( $total_weight >= $minimum_weight  ) {
        // Visualizza un avviso di errore dinamico
        wc_add_notice( sprintf(
            'MESSAGE TO DISPLAY HERE',
            wc_format_weight($total_weight),
            wc_format_weight($minimum_weight)
        ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer code is copied from this answer (2nd answer code): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066649/set-minimum-allowed-weight-for-a-specific-country-in-woocommerce/52067456#52067456